# Android BluetoothLeScanner startScan PendingIntent fails system wide after 28 times

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an Android app use case where I need to "continuously" scan for BLE devices.
This requirement alone probably makes me masochist, and I guess that would make Android my sadist.

I am aware of the [I believe] still not officially documented "no more than 5 scans in 30 seconds" and "no scans for longer than 10 minutes", "no scan results without a ScanFilter", background issues, and a few others.

To mitigate these I use tricks similar to AltBeacon, Nordic Scanner-Compat, SweetBlue, and a few others.

**I don't think any of these are the issue with this post.**

Enter my current problem.

In general my app starts scanning using a PendingIntent for 3.1 seconds and then stops (logical "pause") 3.1 seconds and then repeats (logical "resume") and hard stops after the user specifically signs out of the app.

Below is a log of a 8.1.0 Nexus 6P rebooted and turned on bluetooth and launches my app and starts scanning.
I have no idea why the OS calls `gatt_api` when starting a scan, and why it complains `Context not found` when stopping; perhaps those are clues?

```
2019-07-18 17:51:53.462 13662-13662/? D/AdapterServiceConfig: Adding GattService
2019-07-18 17:51:53.496 13662-13676/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: setProfileServiceState() - Starting service com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService
2019-07-18 17:51:53.497 13662-13662/? I/BtGatt.JNI: classInitNative(L871): classInitNative: Success!
2019-07-18 17:51:53.498 13662-13662/? D/BtGatt.DebugUtils: handleDebugAction() action=null
2019-07-18 17:51:53.499 13662-13662/? D/BtGatt.GattService: Received start request. Starting profile...
2019-07-18 17:51:53.499 13662-13662/? I/bt_btif: get_profile_interface: id = gatt
2019-07-18 17:51:53.504 13662-13662/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: processProfileServiceStateChanged() - serviceName=com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService isTurningOn=false isTurningOff=false isBleTurningOn=true isBleTurningOff=false
2019-07-18 17:51:53.504 13662-13662/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: GattService is started
2019-07-18 17:51:54.251 13662-13697/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(1004)] GATT_Register
2019-07-18 17:51:54.251 13662-13697/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(1027)] allocated gatt_if=3
2019-07-18 17:51:54.274 4384-4435/? D/BluetoothManagerService: Binding Bluetooth GATT service
2019-07-18 17:51:54.277 4384-4384/? D/BluetoothManagerService: BluetoothServiceConnection: com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService
2019-07-18 17:51:54.278 4384-4435/? D/BluetoothManagerService: BluetoothGatt Service is Up
2019-07-18 17:51:54.376 13662-13697/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(1004)] GATT_Register
2019-07-18 17:51:54.376 13662-13697/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(1027)] allocated gatt_if=4
2019-07-18 17:51:54.653 13662-13697/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(1004)] GATT_Register
2019-07-18 17:51:54.653 13662-13697/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(1027)] allocated gatt_if=5
2019-07-18 17:51:54.685 13662-13697/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(1004)] GATT_Register
2019-07-18 17:51:54.685 13662-13697/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(1027)] allocated gatt_if=6

2019-07-18 17:52:00.800 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: resume: #GATT +mBleScannerInternal.startScan(...)
2019-07-18 17:52:00.818 13662-13697/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(1004)] GATT_Register
2019-07-18 17:52:00.818 13662-13697/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(1027)] allocated gatt_if=6
2019-07-18 17:52:00.818 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: resume: #GATT mBleScannerInternal.startScan(...); result=SUCCESS(0)
2019-07-18 17:52:00.836 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: resume: #GATT -mBleScannerInternal.startScan(...)
2019-07-18 17:52:00.837 13349-13349/com.myapp E/MyBleScanner: resume: #GATT mBleScannerInternalStartScanCount=1, elapsedMillisSinceBleScannerInternalStartScanFirstTime=0

2019-07-18 17:52:03.942 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: pause: #GATT +mBleScannerInternal.stopScan(...)
2019-07-18 17:52:03.959 13662-13674/? E/BtGatt.ContextMap: Context not found for info com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService$PendingIntentInfo@2f1237f
2019-07-18 17:52:03.960 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: pause: #GATT -mBleScannerInternal.stopScan(...)
2019-07-18 17:52:03.966 13349-13349/com.myapp I/MyBleScanner: pause: #GATT mScannedDevices(36)={"31:2C:26:FA:91:5E"=null, "0E:06:E5:5D:1F:9D"=null, "0E:05:A0:00:28:E3"=null, "16:05:05:B8:E9:51"=null, "0E:0A:B0:00:13:2E"=null, "0E:0E:A0:05:C9:B4"=null, "74:F0:1C:42:2A:6C"=null, "0E:0C:00:00:0A:14"=null, "0E:0A:00:00:23:38"=null, "0E:05:A0:00:13:AC"=null, "0E:0E:A0:03:CC:16"=null, "0E:0E:A0:02:22:78"=null, "30:8C:FB:D4:BD:B1"=null, "30:8C:FB:7A:55:21"=null, "CD:A3:87:DA:15:D6"=null, "0E:0E:A0:03:C6:D6"=null, "0E:05:A0:00:32:6E"=null, "0E:0E:A0:05:46:FD"=null, "0E:0E:A0:01:0C:DF"=null, "0E:0E:A0:01:14:36"=null, "0E:0E:A0:01:14:56"=null, "0E:0E:A0:03:F7:1A"=null, "0E:0E:43:21:FE:0E"=null, "0E:0E:A0:0E:E2:72"=null, "0E:0E:A0:04:07:1F"=null, "F5:2A:1E:90:43:D7"=null, "0B:F8:B4:90:A2:3A"=null, "0E:0E:A0:00:1E:DF"=null, "0E:05:A0:00:61:B1"=null, "0E:0E:A0:03:DC:D3"=null, "0E:05:A0:00:84:12"=null, "0E:05:A0:00:84:13"=null, "0E:06:E5:59:D8:B3"=null, "0E:0A:A0:01:3D:13"=null, "2F:41:6D:A2:92:C6"=null, "0E:0A:A0:01:3A:69"=null}
2019-07-18 17:52:04.595 13662-13682/? E/BtGatt.GattService: Exception: android.app.PendingIntent$CanceledException

2019-07-18 17:52:07.076 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: resume: #GATT +mBleScannerInternal.startScan(...)
2019-07-18 17:52:07.111 13662-13697/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(1004)] GATT_Register
2019-07-18 17:52:07.112 13662-13697/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(1027)] allocated gatt_if=7
2019-07-18 17:52:07.112 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: resume: #GATT mBleScannerInternal.startScan(...); result=SUCCESS(0)
2019-07-18 17:52:07.127 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: resume: #GATT -mBleScannerInternal.startScan(...)
2019-07-18 17:52:07.127 13349-13349/com.myapp E/MyBleScanner: resume: #GATT mBleScannerInternalStartScanCount=2, elapsedMillisSinceBleScannerInternalStartScanFirstTime=6291

2019-07-18 17:52:10.231 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: pause: #GATT +mBleScannerInternal.stopScan(...)
2019-07-18 17:52:10.238 13662-13674/? E/BtGatt.ContextMap: Context not found for info com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService$PendingIntentInfo@1377141
2019-07-18 17:52:10.239 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: pause: #GATT -mBleScannerInternal.stopScan(...)
2019-07-18 17:52:10.242 13349-13349/com.myapp I/MyBleScanner: pause: #GATT mScannedDevices(37)={"31:2C:26:FA:91:5E"=null, "0E:0E:A0:00:18:EC"=null, "0E:06:E5:5D:1F:9D"=null, "0E:05:A0:00:28:E3"=null, "16:05:05:B8:E9:51"=null, "0E:0A:B0:00:13:2E"=null, "0E:0E:A0:05:C9:B4"=null, "74:F0:1C:42:2A:6C"=null, "0E:0A:00:00:23:38"=null, "0E:0C:00:00:0A:14"=null, "0E:05:A0:00:13:AC"=null, "0E:0E:A0:02:22:78"=null, "30:8C:FB:D4:BD:B1"=null, "30:8C:FB:7A:55:21"=null, "CD:A3:87:DA:15:D6"=null, "0E:0E:A0:03:C6:D6"=null, "0E:0E:A0:05:46:FD"=null, "0E:0E:A0:03:3B:16"=null, "0E:0E:A0:01:14:36"=null, "CD:31:C7:3B:84:0F"=null, "0E:0E:A0:02:0B:C1"=null, "DA:A3:9B:E8:3B:E8"=null, "0E:0E:A0:02:24:97"=null, "0E:0E:A0:03:F7:1A"=null, "0E:0E:43:21:FE:0E"=null, "0E:0E:A0:0E:E2:72"=null, "0B:F8:B4:90:A2:3A"=null, "F5:2A:1E:90:43:D7"=null, "0E:0E:A0:00:1E:DF"=null, "0E:05:A0:00:61:B1"=null, "0E:0E:A0:03:DC:D3"=null, "0E:05:A0:00:84:12"=null, "0E:05:A0:00:84:13"=null, "0E:0A:A0:01:3D:13"=null, "0E:06:E5:59:D8:B3"=null, "2F:41:6D:A2:92:C6"=null, "0E:0A:A0:01:3A:69"=null}
2019-07-18 17:52:10.483 13662-13682/? E/BtGatt.GattService: Exception: android.app.PendingIntent$CanceledException
```

...
The log repeats as expected...except for what may be a tell-tale of `allocated gatt_if=8`, then 9, 10, ..., 31...
...

```
2019-07-18 17:54:43.869 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: resume: #GATT +mBleScannerInternal.startScan(...)
2019-07-18 17:54:43.893 13662-13697/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(1004)] GATT_Register
2019-07-18 17:54:43.893 13662-13697/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(1027)] allocated gatt_if=32
2019-07-18 17:54:43.893 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: resume: #GATT mBleScannerInternal.startScan(...); result=SUCCESS(0)
2019-07-18 17:54:43.912 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: resume: #GATT -mBleScannerInternal.startScan(...)
2019-07-18 17:54:43.913 13349-13349/com.myapp E/MyBleScanner: resume: #GATT mBleScannerInternalStartScanCount=27, elapsedMillisSinceBleScannerInternalStartScanFirstTime=163077
2019-07-18 17:54:43.952 13662-13682/? E/BtGatt.GattService: Exception: android.app.PendingIntent$CanceledException

2019-07-18 17:54:47.021 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: pause: #GATT +mBleScannerInternal.stopScan(...)
2019-07-18 17:54:47.033 13662-13703/? E/BtGatt.ContextMap: Context not found for info com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService$PendingIntentInfo@e09708f
2019-07-18 17:54:47.036 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: pause: #GATT -mBleScannerInternal.stopScan(...)
2019-07-18 17:54:47.037 13349-13349/com.myapp I/MyBleScanner: pause: #GATT mScannedDevices(37)={"0E:0E:A0:02:0D:1A"=null, "0E:06:E5:5D:1F:9D"=null, "0E:0E:A0:00:18:EC"=null, "16:05:05:B8:E9:51"=null, "0E:0E:FF:F6:BE:30"=null, "74:F0:1C:42:2A:6C"=null, "0E:0C:00:00:0A:14"=null, "0E:0A:00:00:23:38"=null, "0E:0E:A0:03:CC:16"=null, "0E:0E:A0:01:0B:E6"=null, "0E:0E:A0:02:22:78"=null, "30:8C:FB:D4:BD:B1"=null, "30:8C:FB:7A:55:21"=null, "CD:A3:87:DA:15:D6"=null, "0E:05:A0:00:32:6E"=null, "0E:0E:A0:03:28:7B"=null, "0E:0E:A0:01:0C:DF"=null, "CD:31:C7:3B:84:0F"=null, "DA:A3:9B:E8:3B:E8"=null, "0E:0E:A0:01:14:56"=null, "0E:0E:A0:02:24:97"=null, "0E:0E:A0:02:15:F8"=null, "37:AB:CB:F6:2D:70"=null, "0E:0E:43:21:FE:0E"=null, "24:B9:20:97:DC:87"=null, "0E:0E:A0:04:6B:34"=null, "0E:0E:A0:04:07:1F"=null, "0B:F8:B4:90:A2:3A"=null, "F5:2A:1E:90:43:D7"=null, "0E:05:A0:00:61:B0"=null, "0E:0E:A0:03:21:34"=null, "0E:05:A0:00:61:B1"=null, "0E:05:A0:00:84:13"=null, "0E:06:E5:59:D8:B3"=null, "0E:0A:A0:01:3D:13"=null, "2F:41:6D:A2:92:C6"=null, "0E:0A:A0:01:3A:69"=null}
2019-07-18 17:54:47.547 13662-13662/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: awakened up at time 187337376
2019-07-18 17:54:47.552 13662-13682/? E/BtGatt.GattService: Exception: android.app.PendingIntent$CanceledException

2019-07-18 17:54:50.143 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: resume: #GATT +mBleScannerInternal.startScan(...)
2019-07-18 17:54:50.173 13662-13697/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(1004)] GATT_Register
2019-07-18 17:54:50.173 13662-13697/? E/bt_stack: [ERROR:gatt_api.cc(1032)] can't Register GATT client, MAX client reached: 32
2019-07-18 17:54:50.173 13662-13697/? E/bt_btif: Register with GATT stack failed.
2019-07-18 17:54:50.173 13662-13697/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(1004)] GATT_Register
2019-07-18 17:54:50.174 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: resume: #GATT mBleScannerInternal.startScan(...); result=SUCCESS(0)
2019-07-18 17:54:50.174 13662-13697/? E/bt_stack: [ERROR:gatt_api.cc(1032)] can't Register GATT client, MAX client reached: 32
2019-07-18 17:54:50.174 13662-13697/? E/bt_btif: Register with GATT stack failed.
2019-07-18 17:54:50.187 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: resume: #GATT -mBleScannerInternal.startScan(...)
2019-07-18 17:54:50.188 13349-13349/com.myapp E/MyBleScanner: resume: #GATT mBleScannerInternalStartScanCount=28, elapsedMillisSinceBleScannerInternalStartScanFirstTime=169351
```

...
**ALWAYS** at **MY** 28th call to startScan (unless perhaps another app has scanned), about 170 seconds, the OS starts reporting `gatt_api` error `can't Register GATT client, MAX client reached: 32`, and at this point:

1. I get a 0 return value and no onScanFailed callbacks that scanning is failing
2. I get no onScanResult callbacks showing any BLE devices scanned

...

```
2019-07-18 17:54:53.291 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: pause: #GATT +mBleScannerInternal.stopScan(...)
2019-07-18 17:54:53.303 13662-13715/? E/BtGatt.ContextMap: Context not found for info com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService$PendingIntentInfo@7eaaf1c
2019-07-18 17:54:53.304 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: pause: #GATT -mBleScannerInternal.stopScan(...)
2019-07-18 17:54:53.304 13349-13349/com.myapp I/MyBleScanner: pause: #GATT mScannedDevices(0)={}
2019-07-18 17:54:56.410 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: resume: #GATT +mBleScannerInternal.startScan(...)
2019-07-18 17:54:56.439 13662-13697/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(1004)] GATT_Register
2019-07-18 17:54:56.439 13662-13697/? E/bt_stack: [ERROR:gatt_api.cc(1032)] can't Register GATT client, MAX client reached: 32
2019-07-18 17:54:56.439 13662-13697/? E/bt_btif: Register with GATT stack failed.
2019-07-18 17:54:56.439 13662-13697/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(1004)] GATT_Register
2019-07-18 17:54:56.439 13662-13697/? E/bt_stack: [ERROR:gatt_api.cc(1032)] can't Register GATT client, MAX client reached: 32
2019-07-18 17:54:56.439 13662-13697/? E/bt_btif: Register with GATT stack failed.
2019-07-18 17:54:56.440 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: resume: #GATT mBleScannerInternal.startScan(...); result=SUCCESS(0)
2019-07-18 17:54:56.458 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: resume: #GATT -mBleScannerInternal.startScan(...)
2019-07-18 17:54:56.458 13349-13349/com.myapp E/MyBleScanner: resume: #GATT mBleScannerInternalStartScanCount=29, elapsedMillisSinceBleScannerInternalStartScanFirstTime=175622
2019-07-18 17:54:59.562 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: pause: #GATT +mBleScannerInternal.stopScan(...)
2019-07-18 17:54:59.576 13662-13673/? E/BtGatt.ContextMap: Context not found for info com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService$PendingIntentInfo@bef4725
2019-07-18 17:54:59.576 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: pause: #GATT -mBleScannerInternal.stopScan(...)
2019-07-18 17:54:59.577 13349-13349/com.myapp I/MyBleScanner: pause: #GATT mScannedDevices(0)={}
2019-07-18 17:55:02.679 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: resume: #GATT +mBleScannerInternal.startScan(...)
2019-07-18 17:55:02.697 13662-13697/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(1004)] GATT_Register
2019-07-18 17:55:02.697 13662-13697/? E/bt_stack: [ERROR:gatt_api.cc(1032)] can't Register GATT client, MAX client reached: 32
2019-07-18 17:55:02.697 13662-13697/? E/bt_btif: Register with GATT stack failed.
2019-07-18 17:55:02.697 13662-13697/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(1004)] GATT_Register
2019-07-18 17:55:02.697 13662-13697/? E/bt_stack: [ERROR:gatt_api.cc(1032)] can't Register GATT client, MAX client reached: 32
2019-07-18 17:55:02.697 13662-13697/? E/bt_btif: Register with GATT stack failed.
2019-07-18 17:55:02.697 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: resume: #GATT mBleScannerInternal.startScan(...); result=SUCCESS(0)
2019-07-18 17:55:02.707 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: resume: #GATT -mBleScannerInternal.startScan(...)
2019-07-18 17:55:02.707 13349-13349/com.myapp E/MyBleScanner: resume: #GATT mBleScannerInternalStartScanCount=30, elapsedMillisSinceBleScannerInternalStartScanFirstTime=181871
2019-07-18 17:55:05.810 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: pause: #GATT +mBleScannerInternal.stopScan(...)
2019-07-18 17:55:05.822 13662-13703/? E/BtGatt.ContextMap: Context not found for info com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService$PendingIntentInfo@82cc0fa
2019-07-18 17:55:05.822 13349-13349/com.myapp V/MyBleScanner: pause: #GATT -mBleScannerInternal.stopScan(...)
2019-07-18 17:55:05.823 13349-13349/com.myapp I/MyBleScanner: pause: #GATT mScannedDevices(0)={}
```

There looks to be some sort of `allocated gatt_if` leak going on here, but I am just calling `startScan(..., mPendingIntent)` and `stopScan(..., mPendingIntent)` with the same final/immutable PendingIntent member, so I am very skeptical that anything in my code is directly causing the "leak".

At this point **NO** apps can scan for BLE devices. Not my app or SweetBlue Toolbox, BLE Scanner, or any other 3rd party BLE scanning app I have tried.

Why the heck is this happening?

When the phone does get in to this state I can get back to a working state by turning the phone's Bluetooth off and back on again.

AltBeacon has a `BluetoothMedic` class that supposedly detects this state and programmatically turns bluetooth off and back on again, but I added it as a dependency and set breakpoints inside of its onScanFailed callback, and it is never called, which defeats the whole purpose of the class, which I find hard to believe is a known issue to them. :/

I would like to not have this leak in the first place and be able to indefinitely stop and start the scanning every 3.1 seconds and reliably scan local devices in range.

Barring that, if I have to I would have to programmatically turn bluetooth off and back on (yes, every 170 seconds...welcome to my hell in the Android BLE world), but without a working startScan return value or onScanFailed callback there is no way to determine if scanning zero devices means that the phone has entered this bad state or there **REALLY** are zero devices around.

I feel confident this code has worked fine for over a year and only recently, max of a few months ago, started to behave this way.

Any hope?

Android BLE really^∞ sucks. :/

Comment: The PendingIntent to use to start scan must be equal to the the one you use to stop scan, according to the `equals` method. So please first test that the `equals` method returns true. If it does, there might be a bug in Android.

Comment: "I am just calling startScan(..., mPendingIntent) and stopScan(..., mPendingIntent) with the same final/immutable PendingIntent member". mPendingIntent never changes; it is equals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update (believed correct)

My final conclusion is that Nordic's Android-Scanner-Compat-Library does create a stoppable PendingIntent, but the problem was that it was calling `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)` when it should have called `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)`

I fixed it on my fork and opened an issue and will be opening a PR.

## Original (close, but not precisely correct)

I believe I found the answer.

Today I wrote a stand-alone app to be the simple test case to repro this problem.
https://github.com/paulpv/AndroidBleStartScanPendingIntentLeak

Go figure, it didn't repro.

One big difference in the test app and my production app is:

1. In the test app I directly call android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.startScan(...)
2. In my production app I use NordicSemiconductor's Android-Scanner-Compat-Library (https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-Scanner-Compat-Library)

My test app didn't repro the problem, but as soon as I tweaked it to use Nordic's Android-Scanner-Compat my problem started to repro.
I undid my changes; no repro.
I redid my changes; repro.
Smoking gun?

Looking at their code I found this:
https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-Scanner-Compat-Library/blob/master/scanner/src/main/java/no/nordicsemi/android/support/v18/scanner/BluetoothLeScannerImplOreo.java#L111

```
final PendingIntent pendingIntent = createStartingPendingIntent(nonNullFilters,
                nonNullSettings, context, callbackIntent);
scanner.startScan(nativeFilters, nativeSettings, pendingIntent);
```

They instantiate their own PendingIntent that wraps mine...
...but nowhere in their code do they keep track of their PendingIntent so that they can successfully call `stopScan(pendingIntent)` with the same pendingIntent.

https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-Scanner-Compat-Library/blob/master/scanner/src/main/java/no/nordicsemi/android/support/v18/scanner/BluetoothLeScannerImplOreo.java#L126

```
final PendingIntent pendingIntent = createStoppingPendingIntent(context, callbackIntent);
scanner.stopScan(pendingIntent);
```

No way those two pendingIntents match up so that the OS can properly stop the scanning.

I confirmed this by adding logging to my fork of their code (search for "pendingIntent=" near every `startScan` and `stopScan`; notice that they are different instances, as well as the growing number in every `allocated gatt_if=`):

```
2019-07-19 21:14:51.230 16905-16905/com.testapp V/BleScannerManager: scan: #GATT +bleScanner.startScan(...)
2019-07-19 21:14:58.424 16905-16905/com.testapp V/BleScannerImplOreo: #GATT startScanInternal: pendingIntent=PendingIntent{1dfc67: android.os.BinderProxy@e560a14}
2019-07-19 21:14:58.468 1447-1941/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(948)] GATT_Register 3c2e1fd9-d3fd-6897-a113-863aa50df781
2019-07-19 21:14:58.468 1447-1941/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(968)] allocated gatt_if=7
2019-07-19 21:14:58.478 16905-16905/com.testapp V/BleScannerManager: scan: #GATT bleScanner.startScan(...); result=SUCCESS(0)
2019-07-19 21:14:58.479 16905-16905/com.testapp V/BleScannerManager: scan: #GATT -bleScanner.startScan(...)
2019-07-19 21:14:58.481 16905-16905/com.testapp E/BleScannerManager: #GATT bleScannerStartScanCount=1, elapsedMillisSinceBleScannerStartScanFirstTime=0
2019-07-19 21:15:03.521 1447-1447/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: awakened up at time 614650173
2019-07-19 21:15:08.250 16905-16905/com.testapp V/BleScannerManager: scan: #GATT +bleScanner.stopScan(...)
2019-07-19 21:15:08.255 16905-16905/com.testapp V/BleScannerImplOreo: #GATT stopScanInternal: pendingIntent=PendingIntent{dc4115f: android.os.BinderProxy@84087ac}
2019-07-19 21:15:08.259 1447-1982/? E/BtGatt.ContextMap: Context not found for info com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService$PendingIntentInfo@77d2d25
2019-07-19 21:15:08.260 16905-16905/com.testapp V/BleScannerManager: scan: #GATT -bleScanner.stopScan(...)
2019-07-19 21:15:08.556 1447-1447/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: awakened up at time 614655208
2019-07-19 21:15:08.570 1447-1554/? E/BtGatt.GattService: Exception: android.app.PendingIntent$CanceledException
2019-07-19 21:15:20.556 16905-16905/com.testapp V/BleScannerManager: scan: #GATT +bleScanner.startScan(...)
2019-07-19 21:15:20.570 16905-16905/com.testapp V/BleScannerImplOreo: #GATT startScanInternal: pendingIntent=PendingIntent{2ce86d6: android.os.BinderProxy@84087ac}
2019-07-19 21:15:20.575 1447-1941/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(948)] GATT_Register 6b444e39-d61a-1d92-52d6-afd6e901b56b
2019-07-19 21:15:20.575 1447-1941/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(968)] allocated gatt_if=8
2019-07-19 21:15:20.576 16905-16905/com.testapp V/BleScannerManager: scan: #GATT bleScanner.startScan(...); result=SUCCESS(0)
2019-07-19 21:15:20.576 16905-16905/com.testapp V/BleScannerManager: scan: #GATT -bleScanner.startScan(...)
2019-07-19 21:15:20.576 16905-16905/com.testapp E/BleScannerManager: #GATT bleScannerStartScanCount=2, elapsedMillisSinceBleScannerStartScanFirstTime=22097
2019-07-19 21:15:23.264 16905-16905/com.testapp V/BleScannerManager: scan: #GATT +bleScanner.stopScan(...)
2019-07-19 21:15:23.269 16905-16905/com.testapp V/BleScannerImplOreo: #GATT stopScanInternal: pendingIntent=PendingIntent{ebafcb0: android.os.BinderProxy@ebb6729}
2019-07-19 21:15:23.272 1447-1982/? E/BtGatt.ContextMap: Context not found for info com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService$PendingIntentInfo@3abaefa
2019-07-19 21:15:23.272 16905-16905/com.testapp V/BleScannerManager: scan: #GATT -bleScanner.stopScan(...)
2019-07-19 21:15:24.968 16905-16905/com.testapp V/BleScannerManager: scan: #GATT +bleScanner.startScan(...)
2019-07-19 21:15:24.980 16905-16905/com.testapp V/BleScannerImplOreo: #GATT startScanInternal: pendingIntent=PendingIntent{8b1626b: android.os.BinderProxy@ebb6729}
2019-07-19 21:15:24.990 1447-1941/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(948)] GATT_Register 0bbb0b8f-2c63-dfc2-268d-fbfe39360ddf
2019-07-19 21:15:24.990 1447-1941/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(968)] allocated gatt_if=9
2019-07-19 21:15:24.990 16905-16905/com.testapp V/BleScannerManager: scan: #GATT bleScanner.startScan(...); result=SUCCESS(0)
2019-07-19 21:15:24.990 16905-16905/com.testapp V/BleScannerManager: scan: #GATT -bleScanner.startScan(...)
2019-07-19 21:15:24.991 16905-16905/com.testapp E/BleScannerManager: #GATT bleScannerStartScanCount=3, elapsedMillisSinceBleScannerStartScanFirstTime=26511
2019-07-19 21:15:25.019 1447-1554/? E/BtGatt.GattService: Exception: android.app.PendingIntent$CanceledException
2019-07-19 21:15:25.795 1447-1941/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(948)] GATT_Register 32a50296-06f2-ed4d-f83c-25da059a4a19
2019-07-19 21:15:25.795 1447-1941/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(968)] allocated gatt_if=10
2019-07-19 21:15:26.046 1447-1447/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: awakened up at time 614672699
2019-07-19 21:15:27.000 16905-16905/com.testapp V/BleScannerManager: scan: #GATT +bleScanner.stopScan(...)
2019-07-19 21:15:27.005 16905-16905/com.testapp V/BleScannerImplOreo: #GATT stopScanInternal: pendingIntent=PendingIntent{40e339d: android.os.BinderProxy@6340012}
2019-07-19 21:15:27.008 1447-1982/? E/BtGatt.ContextMap: Context not found for info com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService$PendingIntentInfo@96b43b4
2019-07-19 21:15:27.009 16905-16905/com.testapp V/BleScannerManager: scan: #GATT -bleScanner.stopScan(...)
2019-07-19 21:15:28.679 1447-1941/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(948)] GATT_Register f119757a-00ff-29b4-72e0-952c5e0db695
2019-07-19 21:15:28.679 1447-1941/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(968)] allocated gatt_if=10
2019-07-19 21:15:28.810 1447-1447/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: awakened up at time 614675462
2019-07-19 21:15:28.822 1447-1554/? E/BtGatt.GattService: Exception: android.app.PendingIntent$CanceledException
```

Looks like I'll have to either open an issue on their repo, or fix it myself and send them a PR.

Thanks to those that chimed in; your questions sent me searching in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not resolved, with 1.4.1! The "listent" PendingIntent is not broadcasted anymore, that's true, but the Bluetooth internal scanning is still not stopped, here is the proof :" BtGatt.ScanManager: awakened up at time".
Test device  : Pixel2 with Android 10

Problem found : 
BluetoothLeScannerImplOreo -> createStartingPendingIntent(...) and createStoppingPendingIntent(...)
in both methods this line of code breaks the normal flow : 
 final int id = callbackIntent.hashCode();

In this way the started pendingIntent hashCode() will be different than the stop pendingIntent hashCode()!! this is bad! it's  a bug, cause the doc clarifies that the two intents must be the same, and in this library case are totally different.

Solution : 
Add "requestCode" as an extra argument to createStartingPendingIntent(..., @NonNull final int requestCode) and createStoppingPendingIntent(..., @NonNull final int requestCode) methods, and use that for id.
  final int id = requestCode; //callbackIntent.hashCode();
And yes, the requestCode must be the same for start and stop.

https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-Scanner-Compat-Library/issues/58#issuecomment-555964455

Answer (score 0):

Definitely something is broken with the stop / start scans. I believe that the startScan with exactly the same callback / pending intent should not start another scan.

Can you post some code here? It seems that your code doesn't stop scan properly. 
Maybe for some reason your PendingIntent differs from one start to another?

Is it reproducible on the other phones?

Comment: "I am just calling startScan(..., mPendingIntent) and stopScan(..., mPendingIntent) with the same final/immutable PendingIntent member". mPendingIntent never changes; it is equals. I cannot post the code, but the above log exhaustively shows every single call I make to startScan and stopScan.

Comment: Please, show the code how you create the PendingIntent.

Comment: Java version of the following Kotlin code that I am writing to attempt to show a simple repro: https://github.com/paulpv/AndroidBleStartScanPendingIntentLeak/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/paulpv/androidblestartscanpendingintentleak/MainActivity.kt#L128 This repo's example code is all in the simple context of an Activity; in reality my production app is running headless as a foreground service; I am attempting to eliminate all of that to produce a simple repro. I'll update when I know more...

Comment: I can't comment your answer (50 rep to comment...). But... You can check original https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner.html#stopScan(android.app.PendingIntent), which says that FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT shouldn't be used. I can see that lib from NordicSemiconductor uses this flag. Worth to check if it is not a problem here.